# The vba code is showing gaps in column after execution

Tags: vba, excel

Two worksheet named "Sheet1" & "Sheet2". In column "D" of worksheet "Sheet1" there are unique numerical values (dynamic rows). In column "A" of worksheet "Sheet2" there are numerical values which are not unique( has many duplicate values) (dynamic rows).

My question is to find match of numerical value of worksheet "Sheet1" of column "D" with worksheet "Sheet2" of column "A" (search from last row) and when first numerical value matches, it should stop searching duplicates and copy cell value of worksheet "Sheet1" column "A" of same row to worksheet "Sheet2" column "C".
The process should continue till all cell values of dynamic column " D" of worksheet "Sheet1". I think I make sense.

I know there are ample of similar question that has been asked in this forum and others but I could not modified the available code to fit my problem. If anybody can help me out to solve the problem. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
Sub offset()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, FR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1=Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 =Worksheets("Sheet2")

For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), xlPrevious)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = c.Offset(, -3)
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

incorrect image:
[image: incorrect image]

correct image:
[image: correct image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Application.Match, pass the returned value back to a variant. Unlike a Long, this can be tested with IsError.

It's generally considered 'bad practice' to name your sub the same as a native VBA function used within the sub.

xlPrevious is an argument for Range.Find, not Application.Match.

```
Sub myoffset()

    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, FR As variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set w1=Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 =Worksheets("Sheet2")

    with ws1
        For Each c In .Range(.cells(2, "D"), .cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
            If not iserror(FR) Then _
              w2.cells(fr, "C") = c.Offset(0, -3).value
        Next c
    end with

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The same problem persist

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and this sub works, but I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim w1 As Worksheet
    Dim w2 As Worksheet
    Dim size1 As Long
    Dim size2 As Long

    'sets references to the respective worksheets
    Set w1 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'gets the absolute last row with data in it for w1 // ignores empty cells
    size1 = w1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'same as previous line but for w2
    size2 = w2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'iterate through the height w1 column D from bottom to top
    For i = size1 To 2 Step -1

        'iterate through the height of w2 column A from bottom to top
        For j = size2 To 2 Step -1

            'tests if the cells are empty so you don't copy blank cells if there are
            'gaps in your data
            If Not IsEmpty(w2.Cells(i, 1).Value) And Not IsEmpty(w1.Cells(i, 4).Value) Then

                'if w2 column A value = w1 column D value
                If w2.Cells(i, 1).Value = w1.Cells(i, 4).Value Then

                    'assign the value in w1 column A to w2 column C
                    w2.Cells(i, 3).Value = w1.Cells(i, 1).Value

                    'exits the nested for loop and returns you to the outer for loop
                    'so you can search using the next criterion
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Ask questions in the comments if I'm close, but not exactly there.

Comment: Thanks jcrizk, I will get back to you soon after testing your code in my office computer tomorrow.

Comment: After vba execution it popup with " Invalid Next control variable reference "

Comment: Convert 'Next c' to 'Next'

Comment: After conversion 'Next c' to 'Next' it popup with " Run-time error '1004':

Comment: With popup "Application-defined or object-defined error "

Comment: I updated my answer and tested it. It works but I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're after. Left me know if this is what you want.

Comment: I wish the code will definitely work and serve the purpose. Since I have no computer at home therefore I have to test the code tomorrow at office. Thank you for your valuable time and efforts that will help me lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to optimize but dont understand what you want to achieve from this line of code

> c.Offset(, -3)

```
Sub offset()

Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, FR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set w1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lrow = w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In w1.Range("D2:D" & lrow)
    FR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), xlPrevious)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("C" & FR).Value = w1.Range(c.address).value
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, I will get back to you soon after testing your code in my office computer tomorrow.

Comment: Before testing comment what you want to do with this line. "c.Offset(, -3)"

Comment: With this line. "c.Offset(, -3)" I want to copy value from "Sheet1" and paste it in "Sheet2" column "C"(Respective row). There are already value in the Column " C" of "Sheet2" but the code should over write in the cell.

Comment: xlPrevious is an argument for Range.Find, not Application.Match.

Comment: The same problem persist